# Why does the weight matrix of the mxnet.gluon.nn.Dense object has no shape?

Tags: mxnet

I try to follow this nice [MXNet Tutorial](https://github.com/zackchase/mxnet-the-straight-dope/blob/master/chapter02_supervised-learning/linear-regression-gluon.ipynb). I create an extremely simple neural network (two input unit, no hidden units and one output unit) doing this:

```
from mxnet import gluon

net = gluon.nn.Dense(1, in_units=2)
```

After that I try to take a look at the shape of the weight matrix (the same way as it is described in the tutorial):

```
print(net.weight)
```

As a result I expect to see this:

```
Parameter dense4_weight (shape=(1, 2), dtype=None)
```

However, I see the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(net.weight)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mxnet/gluon/parameter.py", line 120, in __repr__
    return s.format(**self.__dict__)
KeyError: 'shape'
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You seem to have added an incorrect tag in your question :)

Comment: Which one? It is about mxnet and gluon.

Comment: Read the gluon tag description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a regression that happened [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/commit/1852e2f47d68bb4c2373a359a2a8671b59cd14e5) and has since been fixed on master branch [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/commit/d77d937eaf7e13a30320368d316516bd9da52ca5). Expect it to be fixed in the next MXNet release.